# Program Distance (R) tlength error

Tags: r, distance, unmarked-package

I ran this exact code with some trial data, and it appeared to work just fine, but when I made a larger dataset, R threw an error:

```
Error in unmarkedFrameDS(y = as.matrix(ydat), , survey = "line", dist.breaks=   c(0,:tlength should be a vector with length(tlength)==nrow(y)
```

The line of code I was trying to use is:

```
umf=unmarkedFrameDS(y=as.matrix(ydat),,survey="line",dist.breaks=c(0,100,200,300,400,500,600),tlength=rep(600,5),unitsIn="m")
```

I had 1 set of 4 transects, 600m long each.  When I ran the code, everything went smooth.  But when I combined more sets of transects to the data, I got the error above.

I tried changing the `tlength=rep(600,5)` to `tlength=rep(600,29)`.  28(+1) being the transect count....I think.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Please take the time to make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to make it easier to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion.  I had forgotten to label my transects, and R was assuming that the entire data set was one transect.  Problem solved.